# Game freezes when I enter my house

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It is really annoying that every time I enter my home in any city the game freezes.

It gets past the loading screen and after a few seconds it completely freezes! I'm playing on PC and if anyone has any ideas to fix this please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Is your computer good enough for the game? Just double-check that.

2) Change the settings to: Fullscreen and in the detail bit in options click the `default` button that should set them to your computer specifications.

3) Check and see if there is any mods you have installed that adds stuff to your house. It may be that a mod has put something corrupted or faulty in your house. Just uninstall all subscribed mods then try.

4) Verify the integrity of the cache. You can do this by going to your games library then right clicking the game. Click `Properties` right at the bottom. Next look at the tabs at the top and look for `Local Files`. Finally click `Verify Integrity Of Game Cache...` and see if that comes up with anything!

5) It might be a broken save file. load up a new world and try then, It might be a bit hard as you say it's in your home, but if you google it you might be able to find a way of getting a home straight away.

Hope this helps!

Comment: What mod was it? For future reference :P

Comment: I think it might of been Frostfall as that is my most recent mod

Comment: ok, Is it fixed now?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as I'm not experience this error on my system I would think of 4 possible causes.

1. Check if your system is up 2 date. Check if there is any update for skyrim available.
2. Check your files. If your using steam, you can check if there is an file error (right click > properties > check local files)
3. If you use some mods, disable all of them. Try it again. If it works, you can re-enable one after another until the error occurs again. But beware, don't save your game after the tests. Otherwise you may lost items which are in your inventory. Just take one after another and evaluate the result.
4. If the above don't help, try an older save game and try it again. Maybe start a new game and test it with it too. Just to be sure that it's a new game bug. Maybe just a savegame is broken on your machine.

Comment: Nice to help you.